# Linux Bash Shell Script: How to "ls" a directory and check some output string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm just newbie to Linux Shell Scripting. What i need to know is, normally in the command line, we simply use:

```
# ls /var/log
audit            ConsoleKit     cups        maillog           messages           ntpstats  secure-20130616   spooler-20130623  vsftpd.log-20130616
boot.log         cron           dmesg       maillog-20130616  messages-20130616  prelink   secure-20130623   spooler-20130701  vsftpd.log-20130623
... . . . ..
```

Then

```
# ls /var/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
ls: cannot access /var/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: No such file or directory
```

So with the Shell Script:

- How can i run the command: `# ls /var/aaaaaaaaa`
- and then detect if there is the output string `ls: cannot access` or not?

***Note**: You may ask me whether i want to detect just the Failure. Or the output string. I'm very keen to know the both way. Thank you.*

Comment: Do you really want to check that output string, or just detect failure?

Comment: Actually you may say the FAILURE, to check whether the directory is there or not. But i also keen to know how to check the output strings also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for a directory:

```
if [ ! -d '/var/aaaaaaa' ]; then
   echo 'no dir!'
fi
```

For file:

```
if [ ! -f '/var/aaaaaaa' ]; then
   echo 'no file!'
fi
```

To check output:

```
if ls '/var/aaaaaaa' 2>&1 | grep 'No such'; then  
   echo 'no such'; 
fi
```

To check when ls fails:

```
if ! ls '/var/aaaaaaa' &> /dev/null; then 
  echo 'failed'
fi
```